# What's the best way to access an embedded document in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have a JSON file that I used to create my database in MongoDB, which I am using to build a website. Here is a snippet, before I explain what I'm trying to do.

```
[
    {
    "name": "Field 1",
    "description": "",
    "completed": false,
    "category": "Field",
    "resources": [],
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Field 2",
            "description": "",
            "completed": false,
            "category": "Field",
            "resources": [],
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "Field 3",
                    "description": "",
                    "completed": false,
                    "category": "Field",
                    "resources": [],
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "name": "Topic 1",
                            "description": "",
                            "completed": false,
                            "category": "Topic",
                            "resources": [],
                            "items": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Topic 2",
                            "description": "",
                            "completed": false,
                            "category": "Topic",
                            "resources": [],
                            "items": []
                        }
```

My data (and the way I'd like to use it) is heavily dependent on the parent and children of any individual object. My database has 8 documents, but there's over many embedded objects in total, all embedded at different depths in the 'items' array of each object.

I just created my first draft of the site, which loads the original 8, and upon clicking any of them, it then lists the immediate children in the 'items' array, and it continues doing that until the end of that specific path. To do this, I rely on the index of each object in its array, and keep track of a path

But I would also like my users to be able to navigate directly to the page for a certain object without starting at the top and navigating through. If I wanted to directly access the object for Field 3 in the above example, what's the best way to do this with a single function or piece of code that could work with any of them?

The JSON file that I've used to create my database is 22,000+ lines long, and I'd love to not have to go back and change it more than is absolutely necessary. I was thinking I could add an ID somehow, and if that's unique, I could use that. The names of some objects will be the same, depending on where they are in the data.

EDIT: Bonus question - Would this sort of data be best stored in a relational database? I thought non-relational would be best because of the nested functionality, but I suppose I could make it work with either.

Comment: If you have the path, you can use dot notation to query.

Comment: @Joe I should have specified that I will often times not know what level it’s at.